# Need to get Alexa ranking meaning

Tags: server

Actually I don not know where I have to ask this question. Asking here

"If a website have a ranking 1000 in alexa how much people click or hit the server?"

I need to establish a server. We are aiming to get such traffic. Can anybody share me some suggestion?

Comment: Don't waste your time looking at Alexa

Comment: Agreed but after PR is discontinued then how should we judge credibility of a website?

Answer (score 2):

It's really not worth paying too much attention to Alexa ranking. Alexa can only gather data from those that have their browser toolbars installed - which are mostly webmasters, designers/developers and marketers. So typically a website in the digital industry field is going to have a much better Alexa ranking than those that aren't.

You aren't able to get an accurate number of hits from a site's Alexa ranking. In relation to an Alexa traffic rank, the only data you can use to put into perspective with it's Alexa rank is the data that Alexa themselves provide. These can be seen on the info for [a site](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/moz.com). You can however upgrade to a paid plan to gather more insights but there are much more accurate platforms that can provide more worthwhile information - not that this will relate to Alexa's traffic ranking.

You can learn more on how Alexa source their information and how they get their data [here](http://www.alexa.com/help/traffic-learn-more).

To give you an idea though, a site with an Alexa traffic rank of 1000 will be getting tens of thousands of hits per month. Someone came up with [this conversion](http://www.webs9.com/seo-2/how-to-turn-alexa-traffic-rank-into-unique-visitors) but it's accuracy (as with anything Alexa related) is questionable. So good luck with that one!

Answer (score 1):

My website Alexa is 75,000 and its per day traffic is 600+. However Alexa is sometime misleading as gives results bases on samples i.e it counts only those visits which have installed the Alexa tool-bar rest visitor are out of their radar range. 
For 1000 Alexa I guess you need to have 10000 plus traffic per day.